# vs 2017 and target framework version 9 in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, target-framework

I used to create my apps using visual studio 2019 but for some reason I had to downgrade to vs 2017. my apps used to work properly and I had no problem compiling them on my physical device that has android 10 on it. now i'm getting an error when I open my old apps using vs 2017 that target framework version 9 is not supported. and when I try to create new apps, they won't run on my phone. I tried to change my target framework version but there is only versions up till android 6. i'm trying to install version 9 using the sdk manager but it's not working. I would like to know how to solve this issue. should I reinstall vs 2019. thanks in advance.

I attached a photo to show you what i'm doing to install api 29.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What is Xamarin version? I suspect that your version of Xamarin.Android is 6.x which means that you won't be able to target Android 7.0 or 7.1 even if they are installed through the SDK manager.

You can check the version from **Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio**.

[image]

If you're using Visual Studio 2017 or newer, Xamarin updates are delivered as part of Visual Studio updates. To manually check for updates, go to **Tools > Extensions** and Updates... In the left hand menu, open Updates and select Product Updates. If there are updates available, they will be shown on this list.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for replying sir. I found this ( Xamarin.Android sdk 7.1.0.41). I will add an image of the versions I obtained. I found some updates, i'll update my visual studio anyway and see what happens.

Comment: @ranahd yes, any updates, please let me know.

Comment: @ranahd if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, it is beneficial to others.